# How to import the "connection" class from psycopg2?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I want to import specifically the `connection` class from psycopg2 because I want to specify that the argument to one of my functions is indeed a valid psycopg2 connection.

But I am having trouble locating exactly where it is stored. The doc page is [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html) but I can't seem to find any reference to where it is defined, and poking around in the source code has left me more confused.

So far I have tried:

```
from psycopg2 import connection
from psycopg2.extensions import connection
from psycopg2.extras import connection
from psycopg2.sql import connection
```

But none of them are valid references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it here:

```py
from psycopg2._psycopg import connection
```

But this is an internal object, so you shouldn't do that. It is meant that connection objects are created via `psycopg2.connect()` factory method.

Comment: Thank you. I know it is not standard nor recommended practice, but I am only using it to compare an variable using `isinstance()` to validate that the variable in question is indeed a psycopg2 connection.

Comment: No idea if this was valid at the time of this answer, but today you can use the extensions from psycopg2, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079517/python-type-annotation-for-rare-objects-for-example-psycopg2-objects)

Comment: Thank you @doublethink13 . The link is very helpful. It provides the correct answer.