# python type annotation for rare objects, for example psycopg2 objects

Tags: python, types, annotations, python-typing

I know about builtin types. But how I can specify rare objects, a db connection object for example?

```py
def get_connection_and_cursor() -> tuple[psycopg2.extensions.cursor, psycopg2.extensions.connection]:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host='127.0.0.1', port="5432")
    # connection.autocommit = True
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return connection, cursor
```

Checking the type, here is the output of:

- `type(cursor)`: `psycopg2.extensions.cursor` and
- `type(connection)`: `psycopg2.extensions.connection`.

What should I do with it?

Comment: Please refer to doc. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html

Answer (score 13):

These are custom types (classes) defined by `psycopg2`.

`psycopg2.extensions.cursor` represents a cursor, and

`psycopg2.extensions.connection` represents a connnection.

---

Even builtin-types are classes under-the-hood. Try `type(3)` and you will see it is a class of type `int`.

Create your own class, defining variable and methods like so:

```
class CustomType:
    def __init__(self):   # this is the constructor
        self.x = 3        # this is an instance variable of the class

    def update(self):     # this is an instance method of the class
        self.x += 1       # access instance fields with self param

    @staticmethod         # this is a static method of the class
    def __str__():        # toString equivalent
        return 'abc'
```

Comment: So my line is correct?
`get_connection_and_cursor() -> tuple[psycopg2.extensions.cursor, psycopg2.extensions.connection]`

Comment: Yes, it looks good. Just make sure they are defined to return in the same order as they are eventually returned

Comment: You need to import the needed module. In this case, `import psycopg2`, or `from psycopg2 import extensions` and then use `extensions.cursor`, or `from psycopg2.extensions import cursor` and then use `cursor`, as an example. I guess you imported `pyscopg2` anyway, but in some cases, some modules are indirectly used, in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72342386/11154841) it was MySQLdb which was used by `sqlalchemy` by means of the requirements.txt and which was not imported in the code. I had to import it only for the `typing` module.