# How to find type hints for psycopg2 functions

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

How can one find what type hints to use when annotating my python code for to package functions eg. What will the`psycopg2.connect` return so that I can put it in place of `???` eg:

```
def sql_connect(sql_config: dict = None) -> ???:
        db = psycopg2.connect(
            host=sql_config["host"],
            port=sql_config["port"],
            dbname=sql_config["database"]
        )
        return db
```

Comment: Run the code `print (type(sql_connect()))`

Comment: In [`psycopg2` stubs in typeshed directory](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stubs/psycopg2/psycopg2/__init__.pyi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `psycopg2.connection` as the type hint.

Also check with `type(sql_connect())`

Answer (score 0):

For me the type is `psycopg2.extensions.connection` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65079956/12530258).

The solution in the accepted answer did not work for me for some reason:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> print (type(sql_connect()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sql_connect' is not defined
```